# re-mount two old disk from raid0 setup to recover data

Tags: hard-drive, raid0

I had setup two 500gb disk in RAID0 on my server, but recently suffered a hard disk failure (saw a S.M.A.R.T error on the HDD at boot). My host has put 2 new disk in RAID-0 again (re-installed the OS) and re-attached the old drives on the same machine, so that I can recover the data.

My old drives are:

**/dev/sdb** and **/dev/sdc**

How can I mount these two disks back in RAID0, so that we can recover the data from our old drive? Or is this not possible any more? Have I lost all my data?

This is my **/etc/fstab** and **df -h**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbA1i.png

This is my **fdisk -l**: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=68puYEXD

I read somewhere that you can do this with this command: **mdadm -A --scan** however, it does not yield any result for me -> No arrays found in config file or automatically

Any help/tips/advice regarding this is much appreciated.

Comment: 1. You do not have a raid 0 in use right now. 2. Please show us "mdadm -E /dev/sdc1" and "mdadm -E /dev/sdb5" and "cat /proc/mdstat".

Answer (score 1):

RAID0 and data recovery do not go well together. By using RAID0, you doubled your chances of catastrophic failure. At this point, you have two options:

1. Restore from backup.
2. Send the disks off to a professional data recovery company.

By mucking around with the disks any more yourself, you're just decreasing the chances of ever being able to get data off of them.

Comment: Wish I could give you more than +1. Never, ever, try to mess with this sort of thing yourself, if you value the data at all.